# How to change plot from connecting points to vertical sticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code will  create a plot by connecting points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I change the plot to vertical sticks instead of connecting points? I.e., change to the type of plot of the following example:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `plt.bar`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)
plt.bar(x, y, width=0.08,edgecolor='None',color='k',align='center')
plt.show()
```

[image]